# How do you connect Python RQ worker to a redis server on a unix socket?

Tags: python, redis, python-rq

I'm trying to connect a RQ worker to a Redis server on a Unix domain socket.

I've tried the following

```
$ rq worker --url '/path/to/redis.sock'
Error 111 connecting to None:6379. Connection refused.

$ rq worker --url 'redis:///path/to/redis.sock'
Error 111 connecting to None:6379. Connection refused.

$ rq worker --url 'redis+socket:///path/to/redis.sock'
Error 111 connecting to None:6379. Connection refused.
```

There is mention of a `--socket` flag in a verion of the change log https://github.com/rq/rq/blob/995492878df5f6b7a32614a6050af0f3a4033e2c/CHANGES.md but that doesn't seem to work.

```
$ rq worker --socket --url '/path/to/redis.sock'
Error: no such option: --socket
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct URL syntax for connecting to a Redis server on a unix socket from RQ is `unix:///path/to/redis.sock`

```
$ rq worker --url unix:///path/to/redis.sock
...
```